# Let $X = (-1,1)^{\Bbb N}$ have the product topology. Is the subset $(0,1)^{\Bbb N}$ open?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> Let $X = (-1,1)^{\Bbb N}$ have the product topology. Is the subset $(0,1)^{\Bbb N}$ open?

To consider whether $(0,1)^{\Bbb N}$ is open I know that it is if I can find a basic open set that is a subset of this set, but I'm tangled up with the definitions. Is it that

> $(0,1)^{\Bbb N}$ is open if one can find a basic open set $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} V_n \subset (0,1)^{\Bbb N}$ such that $\color{red}{V_n  = (0,1)^\Bbb N}$ for all but finitely many $n$.

or is it that

> $(0,1)^{\Bbb N}$ is open if one can find a basic open set $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} V_n \subset (0,1)^{\Bbb N}$ such that $\color{red}{V_n  = (-1,1)^\Bbb N}$ for all but finitely many $n$.

I have some confusion with this since we're dealing with a subspace of $(-1,1)^\Bbb N$.

Comment: "I know that it is if I can find a basic open set that is a subset of this set" That's a simplification: for each point in an open set, you have a basic open set that is a subset of this set and also contains that point. So what you really need in this case is "I know that if it is I can find a **non-empty** basic open set that is a subset of this set."

Answer (score 2):

Neither, but the second is closest.

Simply finding a basic open subset is insufficient to show that a set is open (e.g. on the real line, $(0, 1]$ contains the basic open set $(0, 1)$, but $(0, 1]$ is not open). In order to establish that a set $A$ is open with respect to the topology generated by a basis $\mathcal{B}$, you need to show that, for all $x \in A$, there exists a $U \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in U \subseteq A$. That is, every point in the set is contained in a basic open set (again, which is true of most points of $(0, 1]$, but not for $x = 1$).

On the other hand, this means that any non-empty open set must contain at least one basic open set! While this is isn't sufficient to be non-empty and open, it is definitely necessary. This necessary condition matches your second statement. If you can show that this condition is false, then $(0, 1)^\Bbb{N}$ is definitely not open (but the converse is not true in general).

The (usual) basis of the product topology consists of products of open subsets of $(-1, 1)$, taking the form $\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N}} U_n$, such that all but finitely many $\mathcal{U}_n$ are equal to the full space $(-1, 1)$. Does $(0, 1)^\Bbb{N}$ contain any such basic open sets? No it doesn't; any such $\prod_{n \in \Bbb{N}} U_n$ contains points with $0$ coordinates (in $n$th position, where $n$ is such that $\mathcal{U}_n = (-1, 1)$), and $(0, 1)^\Bbb{N}$ contains no such points. Thus, the necessary condition for openness has failed, and $(0, 1)^\Bbb{N}$ is not open in the product topology.

Answer (score 1):

Your space $X$ is the product of infinitely many copies of $(-1, 1)$, so for the basic open in $X$, *that* is the interval that almost all of the $V_n$ must be equal.

(In general, a subbasis of a topological product space $\prod X_n$ is $\prod U_n$ where all but one $U_n$ is $X_n$, and thus a basis will have only finitely many $U_n \neq X_n$. Everyone thinks this is strange the first time they encounter infinite products, and would intuitively go for the so-called box topology instead. But there are deep theoretical reasons why this is objectively the best choice, mostly linked to it being the coarsest topology that makes each coordinate projection continuous.)

And clearly, if some $V_n$ are equal to $(-1, 1)$ (and none of the $V_n$ are empty), then $\prod V_n$ cannot be a subset of $(0, 1)^{\Bbb N}$, as $\prod V_n$ will contain points that have at least some negative coordinates.

Comment: So the second one is the correct one? @arthur

Comment: @Epilogue Yes, your second option is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks! I think one could argue by assuming that if $(0,1)^\Bbb N$ was open then there would exist a basic open set $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} O_n \subset (0,1)^\Bbb N$ such that $O_n = (-1,1)$ for all but finitely many $n$. Now picking $-1/2 \in \prod_{n \in \Bbb N} O_n$ we have that $-1/2 \notin (0,1)^\Bbb N$ which contradicts $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} O_n \subset (0,1)^\Bbb N$. @arthur

Comment: @Epilogue Basically. Except you don't have $-\frac12\in \prod O_n$. That doesn't really make sense, as $\prod O_n$ is not a set of real numbers, it is a set of sequences. You have $-\frac12\in O_k$ for some (or really most) $k$, but $-\frac12\notin (0, 1)$, and from there you eventually get your contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for the lazy notation I was denoting $-1/2$ to be the constant sequence $(-1/2,-1/2, \dots)$, but I think that this element is also not neccessarily in $\prod O_n$. @arthur

Comment: @Epilogue That wouldn't necessarily work either, no. Sure, some sequence where _most_ of the entries are $-\frac12$ would be in $\prod O_n$, but it is a little cumbersome to eke out an exact phrasing of whta you want to do. It's a good idea, but I just don't know of an elegant way to write it rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

For any product of topological spaces $X_i$, if $U\subseteq \prod_{i\in I} X_i$ is open and non-empty, and $\pi_j:\prod_{i\in I} X_i\to X_j$ is the projection onto the $j$th factor, then necessarily $\pi_j(U) = X_j$ for all but finitely many $j$.

This is because if we take $x\in U$, then there is some basic open set $V$ with $x\in V\subseteq U$ (that is, $V = \bigcap_{k=1}^m \pi_{j_k}^{-1}(U_k)$ for some $j_1, ..., j_m\in I$ and $U_k\subseteq X_{j_k}$ open), and then we have the inclusions $\pi_j(U)\supseteq \pi_j(V)$, and since $\pi_j(V) = X_j$ for all but finitely many $j$ (it holds for all $j\in I\setminus\{j_1, ..., j_m\}$), the same must hold for $\pi_j(U)$.

In particular, $\pi_n((0, 1)^\mathbb{N}) = (0, 1)\neq (-1, 1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and the above condition doesn't hold. The set cannot be open.